# How to send command to python script?

Tags: python

I have a python script running in background via nohup.
It is an alarm system. Once I run the script it checks if a motion is detected.
Now i have the problem of how to disable the alarm.
Could you help me to find a good way to send a command to disable/kill the running script?

Quick and dirty method was:
Checking a txt file content: if I want to shut down the script, I modify the txt.

Something like:

```
if txt content is "disable":
quit
```

I am pretty new to python maybe you can help me.

Comment: What OS are you running the script on?

Comment: I run it on LINUX. Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser("~/disable_alarm.txt")):
     #then dont sound alarm
```

and just put a file in your home directoy when you want it disabled ...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using linux/unix/macos, you can kill the script from the command line

```
$ ps aux | grep python
nate     16210  0.2  0.0  20156  5176 pts/2    S+   17:02   0:00 python3
nate     16215  0.0  0.0   8044   932 pts/1    S+   17:02   0:00 grep python
```

The second field is the PID of the running process, kill it with the kill command:

```
$ kill 16210
$ ps aux | grep python
nate     16220  0.0  0.0   8044   932 pts/1    S+   17:02   0:00 grep python
```

To grab the pid automatically, you can add this to the top of your python script:

```
import os
pid = os.getpid()
with open('pid', 'w') as procfile:
    procfile.write(pid)
```

Now, you can grab that pid with one line of bash:

```
kill -TERM $(cat pid)
```

replace `pid` with the location of the file `pid`

Comment: Thank you, But how could i use this automatically? I have to look for the process ID every time. That takes too long.